# Some (maybe) basic estimate of expected values involving brownian motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have the following estimation in a paper I'm reading about Brownian Motion on a Torus:
$$
1+\theta\ \mathbb E_x[\tau_A] + \sum_{i=2}^\infty \left(\theta\sup_{x\in\mathbb T_2}\mathbb E_x[\tau_A]\right)^i \leq \exp\left(\theta\mathbb E_x[\tau_A] + 2\theta^2 \sup_{x\in\mathbb T_2}\mathbb E_x[\tau_A]^2\right)
$$
where $\mathbb T_2$ is a Torus, $A\subset\mathbb T_2$ closed, $x\in\mathbb T_2$ and $0<\theta<\frac 1 2 \sup_{x\in\mathbb T_2}\mathbb E_x[\tau_A]^{-1}$.

**Ideas:** To prove this,  I have already tried the Taylor series of $e^x$, the geometric sum, the Jensen inequality and a few other things, however nothing worked so far.

I'd be really glad if you could give me some thoughts about what else to do.

Comment: Did you forget a $\theta$ in the expenntial? Otherwise $\theta\to 0$ shows this cannot hold

Comment: Yep, you are correct. I added the $\theta$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with probablitities.

Set $x = \theta \mathbb E_x[\tau_A]$ and $y = \theta \sup_y \mathbb E_y[\tau_A]$. Then $0 x \leq y < \frac{1}{2}$. By the geometric series we get
$$ \sum_{i=2}^\infty y^i = \frac{1}{1-y} - 1 - y = \frac{y^2}{1-y} < 2 y^2.$$
Hence
$$ 1 + x + \sum_{i=2}^\infty y \leq 1 + x + 2y^2 \leq \exp(x+2y^2).$$
The last step uses the inequality
$$1+z \leq \exp(z), \forall z > 0,$$ which follows from the Taylor expansion
$$ \exp(z) = 1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2} + \dotsb.$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are missing a $\theta$ in the exponential, this is just
$$
1+z\leq e^{z}
$$
for $z\geq 0$.